# Concatenate the result of a string function in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, string-concatenation

The mysteries of typescript have reared their head again. I have a typescript class User that has a few properties firstName, lastName, eMail etc. It also has a toString() function.

```
export class User {

  id = '{}';
  selected?= false;
  firstName = '<First Name>';
  lastName = '<Last Name>';
  eMail? = '<E Mail>';
  createdDate? = new Date(Date.now());
  updateDate?: Date;

  // tried this??
  //toString = () => this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;

  // and also this??
  toString() {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
  }
}
```

The function toString() is meant for messages, dialogs and so on but when I try and use it in a string concatenation I get [object Object].

`You are editing user ' + this.user.toString();`

results in:

`You are editing user [object Object]`

I have read up on instance functions and prototype functions and have tried both of them. I have also made sure that firstName and lastName are really strings.

Why this strange behaviour? Am I not allowed to concatenate the results of a function?

Comment: `this.user` is guaranteed to be an instance of `class User`…? You're calling *that* `toString` function? Have you confirmed that, e.g. by adding a `console.log` inside that `toString` function?

Comment: It works quite well with tsc 2.5.2 and node v8.4.0 I think "this.user" is not an instance of User.